# how do I create random numbers between 6-314 and 6-194 in assembler?

Tags: assembly, dos, 2d-games, dosbox

I need to create a random point on the screen in assembly in graphic mode (I use tasm and dosbox 8086, I don't know if it matters.) I have a function that will do it with x and y cords but I don't know how to create the random numbers. Can someone please send a function that would do that? I barely understand anything in assembly and have to make a simple game until this Saturday. Also the random number has to in word format, not bite.

Comment: What is “6-314” supposed to mean?  Do you mean “between 6 and 134”?  Or “between 6314 and 6194?”  Your question is unclear.  That said, the answer is to write a random number generator.  Many examples exist only (like e.g. the xorshift random number generator).

Comment: @fuz I think he means generate a number between 6 and 314 and another between 6 and 194. I assume he wants to plot a random pixel in a 320x200 video mode that has a 6 pixel region (border?) around the edge where he doesn't want to plot.